# Htaccess redirects my php extensions to example domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have no htaccess in my root. But everytime I try to access www.mydomain.com/index.php or any other link that ends with .php it directs me to

```
http://example.com/folder/index
```

I can't access by doing mydomain.com everything has to have www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Fixed itself. Seems it took a little bit to refresh.